# How to detect tap on UITextField for Swift 2?

Tags: ios, swift2, uitextfield

Is there an documentation or example on how do I do it in Swift 2?

I have read many articles but it doesn't provide much details beside jumping into the codes which are mostly done in Objective-C / Swift 1.

Answer (score 1):

You can set tag on textfield in Attribute Inspector or through programatically

```
 myTextfield.tag = 1 //AnyValue
 myTextfield.delegate = self
```

Now, Implement textfield delegate method and check for which textfield edited

```
 func textFieldShouldBeginEditing(textField: UITextField) -> Bool {

    if textField.tag == 1{
       //do here you want
    }
    return true
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check if a `UITextField` became first responder to know if one was tapped. You need to set the delegate of `UITextField` for example:

```
@IBOutlet weak var textField: UITextField! { didSet { textField.delegate = self } }
```

Where self is a `UIViewController` conforming to `UITextFieldDelegate`

Now you can check if a `UITextField` became first responder with:

```
func textFieldShouldBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    print("textField did became first responder")
    return true
}
```

You return true to let the textfield become first responder (unless that is not the behaviour you wish, then return false) and before the return statement you can do anything you want.